# Download the USB installer on macOS X Catalina

Tags: mac-appstore, catalina

I'm trying to download the USB installer of macOS X Catalina but I'm getting an error:

`Update not found The requested version of macOS is not available.`

I'm already on mac os Catalina `10.15`, I'm not trying to update, I want to download the USB installer.

Below the error I'm receving, a screenshot and a gif.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/372698#372698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15`

See also [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/372698#372698)

Comment: This command doesn't work on macOS Mojave. Running it just displays the man page for `softwareupdate`.